# How to compare NSUUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uuid, nsuuid

What is the best (least code, fastest, most reliable) way to compare two `NSUUIDs`?

Here is an example:

```
-(BOOL)isUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid1 equalToUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid2
{
    return ... // YES if same or NO if not same
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the NSUUID class reference:

> Note: The NSUUID class is not toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation’s
>   CFUUIDRef. Use UUID strings to convert between CFUUID and NSUUID, if
>   needed. Two NSUUID objects are not guaranteed to be comparable by
>   pointer value (as CFUUIDRef is); use isEqual: to compare two NSUUID
>   instances.

So just use the following:

```
-(BOOL)isUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid1 equalToUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid2
{
    return [uuid1 isEqual:uuid2];
}
```

Comment: Is the comparison necessary as [nil isEqual:uuid2] would also return NO, correct?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to create an extra method for this, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that

> NSUUID objects are not guaranteed to be comparable by pointer value
>   (as CFUUIDRef is); use isEqual: to compare two NSUUID instances.

So just do `BOOL sameUUID = [uuid1 isEqual:uuid2];`

Comment: I would be interested in the reason for a down-vote.

Comment: The "extra method"'s purpose is only to explain the question further. I'd be interested in the reason for a down-vote on the question too ;-).

Answer (score 3):

NSUUID effectively wraps uuid_t.

Solution...

```
@implementation  NSUUID ( Compare )



- ( NSComparisonResult )  compare : ( NSUUID * )  that
{
   uuid_t   x;
   uuid_t   y;

   [ self  getUUIDBytes : x ];
   [ that  getUUIDBytes : y ];

   const int   r  = memcmp ( x, y, sizeof ( x ) );

   if ( r < 0 )
      return  NSOrderedAscending;
   if ( r > 0 )
      return  NSOrderedDescending;

   return  NSOrderedSame;
}



@end
```

Comment: This is so important, since NSSortDescriptor uses compare: method. I used NSFetchedRequest with NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor that was sorting by uuid attribute and got crash (no compare: selector is present with NSUUID) - this fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable simple way to accomplish this is to use string comparison. However, a method that utilizes the underlying `CFUUIDRef` may be faster.

```
-(BOOL)isUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid1 equalToUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid2
{
    return [[uuid1 UUIDString] isEqualToString:[uuid2 UUIDString]];
}
```